# Variables not being recognised on python

Tags: python

I am creating a game on python which requires names of songs to have a few characters removed from them. Here is an example of one:

```
abbasong = ('Dancing Queen by ABBA')

removed = abbasong.replace("d", "q", "")

print removed
```

However, when I run the program, the computer tells me I have a syntax error, and highlights removed. 
Does anyone know where I am going wrong?

This is the error I am receving:
[Error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oB7SI.png)

Comment: Can you post your full traceback?

Comment: Please read [mcve] and include the exception traceback in your question.

Comment: which version of python you are using ?

Comment: And if you're running Python 3, note that it's now `print(removed)` with parentheses.

Comment: I think what you want to do is replacing "d" or "q" with "", i.e. removing "d" and "q". This could be done by using `abbasong.replace("d", "")` and `abbasong.replace("q", "")` without changing code logic too much. Taking care of case! `"q" != "Q"`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a problem in the `abbasong.replace` statement. When you face such issues, its best to first consult the help from the interpreter:

```
replace(self, old, new, count=-1, /)
    Return a copy with all occurrences of substring old replaced by new.

      count
        Maximum number of occurrences to replace.
        -1 (the default value) means replace all occurrences.
```

The third argument needs to be an int. It can't be empty string `""`. This is what the traceback says too:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'str' object cannot be interpreted as an integer
```

If you put there an integer, it works as you expect it to be.

But if you face `Syntax Error`, it's probably in the `print` statement. Python3 uses `print()` while Python2 uses `print`. Try changing this statement.

However, there is also a difference between Upper and lowecase characters. "D" is not as same as "d", so `removed` would be empty in your case.

Comment: Even if that is so, that's not the error the OP experiences.

Comment: You're right, I updated to relate the print command which is probably the issue